# How to create a CMS signature using a Luna SA (HSM)

Tags: c#, signing, pkcs#7

I am trying to create a CMS signature from a Luna SA (HSM) from C# in order to create an x-pkcs7 s/mime message.

What singing mechanism should I be using?

Regards